# integrating by parts for homogeneus function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to determine the relation between $r\int_{B_{r}(0)}|\nabla u|^2$ and $\int_{\partial B_r(0)}u^2\,dS$, when $u$ is homogeneus of degree $k$.

My approach: After integrating by parts, we have
$$\int_{B_r(0)}\nabla u\cdot \nabla u \,dx= -\int_{B_r(0)}u\Delta u+\int_{\partial B_r(0)}u\cdot\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\,dS$$

I know that $u$ is homogeneus of degree $k$, then $u_{x_i}(\lambda x)=\lambda^{k-1}u_{x_i}(x)$, but i don't know how i can continue. Any hint will be appreciated, thanks!!!